# Custom p:radioButton does not work inside a table: id of select not found

Tags: jsf, primefaces, radio-button

I have a table, and I want to put inside any row of this table a custom `p:radioButton`, on two different columns.

This is the code of the `p:selectOneRadio`:

```xhtml
<p:selectOneRadio 
    value="#{bean.val}"
    id="val"
    required="true" 
    layout="custom"
>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="A" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="B" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

and this is the code of one of the `radioButton`:

```xhtml
<p:radioButton for="tabs:table:#{i}:val" itemIndex="0"/>
```

I checked with the browser and the id is right. Anyway, I get this error:

> javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component 'tabs:table:0:val' in view.

What could be the problem? Please help :)

I'm using Primefaces 3.4.1 with Mojarra 2.1.7

Comment: @JasperdeVries: excuse me, I added them

Comment: @BalusC But the `p:selectOneRadio` is inside a table. How can I differenziate between a component of a row from another? (And anyway, the id is correct, why Primefaces says me it's not?)

Comment: It works. I don't know why, but it work. BalusC never fails :D 

Can someone inform BalusC that if he write the answer I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was simple, and it was suggested to me by [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc):

```html
<p:radioButton for="val" itemIndex="0"/>
```